# Draw shape on bitmapData, transparency lost

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe

I am drawing a rounded rect into BitmapData: (bg)

```
var bg:Shape= new Shape();
bg.graphics.beginFill(0xdddddd);
bg.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 200, 400, 20);
bg.graphics.endFill();

var imageData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bg.width, bg.height);
image.draw(bg);
```

But when I create a Bitmap from imageData the bitmap corners are not transparent as expected, instead its white color .. any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
// see the argb color value 0x00000000 -> the first two '0' after '0x' are for transparency
var imageData:BitmapData = new BitmapData( bg.width, bg.height, true, 0x00000000 );
```

Comment: BitmapData is transparent by default, also, 0x00000000 is the same as 0, as 0x means hex-number

Comment: but b y default the color is white not transparent, i just pointed out the argb color value ;) sure you can put 0